Map is null but map value is rendering in react-leaflet
I have a condition to open Popup But it gives error map is null.
In this code when controlInfoWindow is true then popup will open. The map and marker value is not null as it return value in console.
const controlInfoWindow = () => {
const marker = markerRef?.current;

    if (map != null && marker != null) {
      if (totalDeviceBtnClick == true) {
        return true;
      } else if (props.filter) {
        return true;
      } else if (
        props.routeControl == 0 &&
        props.areaFenceControl == 0 &&
        props.showPopUpBox == false &&
        props.ambulanceTraumaMedLatLng.length == 0
      ) {
        if (
          marker !== null &&
          typeof marker == "object" &&
          Object.keys(marker).length !== 0
        ) {
        }
        return true;
      } else if (
        props.routeControl == 1 &&
        props.areaFenceControl == 0 &&
        props.showPopUpBox == true
      ) {
        // marker?.openPopup();
        return true;
      } else if (
        props.routeControl == 0 &&
        props.areaFenceControl == 1 &&
        props.showPopUpBox == true
      ) {
        // debugger;
        return true;
      } else if (
        props.routeControl == 1 &&
        props.areaFenceControl == 1 &&
        props.showPopUpBox == true
      ) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }

};

useEffect(() => {
const marker = markerRef?.current;
if (controlInfoWindow() == true && map != null) {
if (
marker !== null &&
typeof marker == "object" &&
Object.keys(marker).length !== 0
) {
marker?.openPopup();
}
}
}, [map, markerRef.current, controlInfoWindow]);

The map is rendered by useMap:
const [map, setMap] = useState();
const MyMap = ({ setMap }) => {
const map = useMap();

useEffect(() => {
setMap(map);
}, []);

return null;
};
*

Map value in console is like this
*Object { options: {…}, handlers: (7) […], layers: {…}, zoomBoundLayers: {…}, sizeChanged: false, container: div.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch.leaflet-fade-anim.leaflet-grab.leaflet-touch-drag.leaflet-touch-zoom, leaflet_id: 2, containerId: 3, fadeAnimated: true, panes: {…}, … }

Marker value :
Object { options: {…}, latlng: {…}, initHooksCalled: true, popup: {…}, events: {…}, popupHandlersAdded: true, leaflet_id: 632, firingCount: 0, eventParents: {…}, mapToAdd: {…}, … }

The full code:
<MapContainer
  style={{ height: "100%" }}
   center={path?.length == 0 && props?.areaFenceControl == 0 ? apiData.length > 0
            ? { lat: mapData?.latitude, lng: mapData?.longitude }
             : { lat: 20.3341125, lng: 85.8012031 }
            : center
          }
    ref={mapRef}
    zoom={zoom}
    minZoom={parseInt(process.env.REACT_APP_MAP_MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL)}
    scrollWheelZoom={true}
  >
  <TileLayer url={osm.maptiler.url} attribution={osm.maptiler.attribution} />
  <MyMap setMap={setMap} />
  <MapEvents />
  <Marker key={index} ref={ index == props.targetedVehicle ? markerRef : null }
          position={{lat: val.latitude,  lng: val.longitude }}
          icon={OSMIcon}
          eventHandlers={{ click: () => popUpOpenBox(index) }} >
  <Popup closeButton={true}>
      A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
  </Popup>
<MapContainer />


When i open inspect element also receives an error map is null.

When we open inspect element, it hides some part of the page in which map is also included, due to this it gives error and without opening the inspect tab it works fine.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this eror.
